# The first execution of app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

It's necessary to do something at the first execution of Windows Phone 7 app. How can I check up, is the execution first?

Comment: First launch after install? No, you don't need to do anything, if this is don't necessary for application logic

Comment: What does this comment even mean??

Comment: Sorry, I read first sentence as a question... Sorry one more time

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IsolatedStorage` for this. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769510%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for details. For a basic implementation see [this link](http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/09/03/Using-Isolated-Storage-on-Windows-Phone-7.aspx).

Upon first launch and before you even setup the persisted default settings you can count the number of saved settings:

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Count == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("No setting avalible - applications fisrt launch!");
```

I would place this in the MainPage's constructor.

This should be all you need. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend you use IsolatedStorage, but specifically add a boolean key to the isolated storage, and then verify if it's set to true.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

/// <summary>
/// Application Settings
/// </summary>
public class AppSettings
{
    /// <summary>
    /// IsFirstStart IsolatedStorage Key.
    /// </summary>
    public const string IsFirstStartKey = "firststart";

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is the first start.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <c>true</c> if this instance is the first start; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public static bool IsFirstStart
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(AppSettings.IsFirstStartKey))
                return (bool)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[AppSettings.IsFirstStartKey];
            else
                return true;
        }
        set
        {
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(AppSettings.IsFirstStartKey))
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[AppSettings.IsFirstStartKey] = value;
            else
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add(AppSettings.IsFirstStartKey, value);

            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if (AppSettings.IsFirstStart == false)
{
    // First Start, do some logic
    // ...

    // But remember to set it to true, once it's done!
    AppSettings.IsFirstStart = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put code in various events that are described in the application lifestyle

The link below which shows the application lifecycle of a windows phone app and shows the 4 events that appear in your App.xaml.cs file

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/block-diagram-on-windows-phone-7-application-life-cycle-even/

Answer (score 0):

or in less lines
You can do a verification in

private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
    }

save a variable in the isolated storage. 
try the get it if you can't that means it's the first time you use the application, but if you are able to load the variable then the application was already start.

hope it help